# instancing new object in for loop in Java

Tags: java

when I compile this code every thing is okay

```
class TreeCutter {
    public static void main ( String [] args ){
         for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ ){
                  TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
          }
}
```

but when I remove brace and compiled my code

```
class TreeCutter {
    public static void main ( String [] args ){
         for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ )
                  TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
   }
}
```

I gave error:

```
main.java:12: not a statement
            TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
            ^
main.java:12: ';' expected
            TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
                      ^
2 errors
```

I want to know what happened behind of this code.

Comment: The term is *instantiating*, not *instancing*.

Comment: Even in 1st case you missed one closing braces{...}.

Comment: I am not sure if your code will compile even if you add the missing brace. See my answer below

Comment: You have edited your question, so show us the complete code for `TreeCutter` class. Where does `testCaseNum` and `commandPrompt` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the above code will **STILL NOT compile** even if you add the missing brace for main method. In order to make it compile you need to do it like this

**Without brace for FOR loop**

```
class TreeCutter {
    public static void main ( String [] args ){
         TreeCutter TC ;
         for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ )
                  TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
    }
}
```

**With Brace for FOR loop**

```
class TreeCutter {
    public static void main ( String [] args ){

         for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ ) {
                  TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
         }
    }
}
```

As far as GC is concerned the scope of the TC is in for loop only. So until you pass the TC out of for loop it will be eligible for GC the moment next iteration of for loop runs

Comment: I know what do you talking about but if I add main brace I still have error.

Comment: Yes you got it. But what I posted will fix your error.

Comment: thanks. but i want to know if i use brace it force garbage collector to delete my object or not.and what happened behind.

Comment: If you use brace the scope of the TC is in for loop only. So until you pass the TC out of for loop it will be eligible got GC the moment next iteration of for loop runs.

Comment: thanks i got my answer. please add it to your answer and i can add it for answer of my question.

Comment: your comment is my answer and i think it's better to add it in your answer.

Comment: added the comment to answer

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing braces for `main(){...`

Comment: thank for fast reply I edit my code and still have this error

Comment: @saman either you didn't provide the full code, or you should get compilation errors for unrecognized variables `testCaseNum` and `commandPrompt`

Comment: See my answer below :)

Comment: @vkg your answer is the same as mine (closing braces)

Comment: @alfasin With all due respect to you  I don't this so. you missed the another compilation error. But it's okay if you think so.

Comment: @vkg it has nothing to do with respect ;) your answer covers a case where in the for-loop there's more than one line of code, only that this other case doesn't apply to his code. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

Missing the closing braces for `main()` method.

For `for loop` statement following one line code, you can't omit braces `{}` if you are trying to create object and assign it to a variable, the following code can't compile

```
 for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ )
     TreeCutter TC = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
```

But can compile like that;

```
TreeCutter tc;                        
for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ )
    tc = new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );    

OR

for( int i = 0 ; i < testCaseNum ; i ++ )
    new TreeCutter( commandPrompt );
```

Comment: i omit main brace and edit my question.thank for reply

Comment: thanks. but i want to know what happened behind of that when i tried to compile.